# The c.d.f. of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

if you have a continuous random variable X whose c.d.f. is F(x) for any x, and you have Y = 2X, then we know that the p.d.f. of Y is g(y) = $\frac{1}{2}g(\frac{1}{2}y)$. I would like to know if we can say that the c.d.f. of Y is G(y) = $F(\frac{1}{2}y)$, without any "plus constant C" that follows. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you mean that $g(y)=\frac{1}{2}f^{}_X\left( \frac{1}{2} y \right)$. For the CDF, yes, since $Y=2X$, then$$P(Y\le y) = P\left(2X\le y\right) = P\left(X\le \frac{1}{2}y\right)$$

Comment: @Joe Yes I meant $g(y) = \frac{1}{2}f_{X}(\frac{1}{2}y)$, thanks for pointing it out! And thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome.